# Quebrar linha depois de uma quantidade de caracteres sem cortar a palavra

Tags: java

Estou tentando resolver um pequeno dojo de java:

*Escreva um programa em que dado uma frase e a quantidade de colunas que podem ser exibidas na tela, faça a quebra de linhas sem quebrar as palavras.
Por exemplo, se passarmos a frase "Um pequeno jabuti xereta viu dez cegonhas felizes." e pedirmos para ela ser exibida em 20 colunas, teremos como resposta:*

```
Um pequeno jabuti
xereta viu dez
cegonhas felizes.
```

Porém no meu código ele está quebrando a palavra depois do 20 caracter.

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        String texto = "Um pequeno jabuti xereta viu dez cegonhas felizes.";
        String novoTexto = "";
        int contadorQntLetras = 0;
        int limiteLinha = 20;

        for( int i = 0; i < texto.length(); i++ ) {
            novoTexto += texto.charAt(i);
            contadorQntLetras++;

            if( contadorQntLetras >= limiteLinha) {
                contadorQntLetras = 0;
                novoTexto += "\n";
            }
        }

        System.out.println(novoTexto);
    }
```

Resultado:

```
Um pequeno jabuti xe
reta viu dez cegonha
s felizes.
```

Answer (score 1):

O problema é que você está contando somente as letras, desconsiderando o conceito das palavras.

Neste caso, uma opção é dividir o texto de entrada por espaços, gerando um array de  palavras. Depois iterar sobre o array de palavras para reconstruir o texto,  lembrando de colocar a verificação de quebra de linha antes de concatenar uma palavra:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  String texto = "Um pequeno jabuti xereta viu dez cegonhas felizes.";
  StringBuilder novoTexto = new StringBuilder();

  String[] palavras = texto.split(" ");

  int contadorQntLetras = 0;
  int limiteLinha = 20;

  for (String palavra : palavras) {

    if(contadorQntLetras + palavra.length() >= limiteLinha) {
      contadorQntLetras = 0;
      novoTexto.append('\n');
    }

    novoTexto.append(palavra);
    novoTexto.append(' ');
    contadorQntLetras += palavra.length() + 1;
  }
  System.out.println("Result");
  System.out.println(novoTexto);
}
```